# how to scroll up the expansion panel automatically when it expanded and it is in bottom of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

When user click to expand the panel, it will expand but at the bottom of the screen which is not visible unless they scroll up.

Is there a way for the expanded panel to move up when user press to expand it if it's at the bottom of the page?